# Conversion Error setting value 'dbaccess.persistence.Employee[id=66666666]' for 'null Converter'

Tags: jsf, converters

Here's a snippet of the form I'm trying to submit:

```
<h:outputText value="Employees"></h:outputText>
<h:selectManyListbox id="employees" 
                     value="#{lookupControl.memberEmployees}" 
                     converter="#{employeeConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{lookupControl.employees}" 
                   var="emp" 
                   itemLabel="#{emp.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER}" 
                   itemValue="#{emp}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
<h:message id="employeesMsg" 
           for="employees" 
           errorStyle="color:red; display:block" 
           styleClass="errorMessage"/>

<h:outputText value="Project Lead"></h:outputText>
<h:selectOneListbox id="projectLead" 
                    value="#{lookupControl.chosenLead}" 
                    converter="#{employeeConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{lookupControl.employees}" 
                   var="emp" 
                   itemLabel="#{emp.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER}" 
                   itemValue="#{emp}"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
<h:message id="projectLeadMsg" 
           for="projectLead" 
           errorStyle="color:red; display:block" 
           styleClass="errorMessage"/>
```

And here's the converter `employeeConverter`:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "employeeConverter")
public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // hack to get an em
        HelperBean helper = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{helperBean}", HelperBean.class);
        EntityManager em = helper.getEm();

        System.out.println(value);

        Employee tmp = DBHelper.findEmployee(em, value);
        return tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        Employee tmp = (Employee) value;
        return tmp.getEMPLOYEE_NUMBER();
    }
}
```

The idea being that a "Project" (the object being created when this form is submitted) has a list of members (`List<Employee>`) and a team leader (`Employee`). When I try submitting the form, I get a message along the lines of:

```
Conversion Error setting value 'dbaccess.persistence.Employee[id=66666666]' for 'null Converter'.
```

It's saying it can't convert from a String to an Employee, but it worked for the field right above it. I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "null converter" is the exception that the converter instance cannot be found. Since you're referencing the converter as a managed bean by converter="#{employeeConverter}, it would only be found if it's annotated with @javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean

Add @ManagedBean(name = "employeeConverterBean") into class EmployeeConverter

```
@ManagedBean(name = "employeeConverterBean")
@FacesConverter(value = "employeeConverter")
public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter {
```

and use `converter="#{employeeConverterBean}"` instead of `converter="#{employeeConverter}"`

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a scoped variable in your `converter=` attribute, but `@FacesConverter` does not create a scoped variable.  Rather, it registers your converter class with the *converter ID* you specify.

From the [documentation for FacesConverter.value](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/FacesConverter.html#value%28%29):

> The value of this annotation attribute is taken to be the *converter-id* …

Remove the `converter=` attribute entirely from your h:selectManyListbox, and instead, add a nested f:converter element:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="employees" 
                     value="#{lookupControl.memberEmployees}">
    <f:converter converterId="employeeConverter"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{lookupControl.employees}" 
                   var="emp" 
                   itemLabel="#{emp.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER}" 
                   itemValue="#{emp}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

**Update:** I'd always taken the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyListbox.html) literally, which says the attribute's value "must evaluate to javax.faces.convert.Converter".  BalusC points out that a nested f:converter is not needed;  passing a literal converter ID in the `converter=` attribute will work:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="employees" 
                     value="#{lookupControl.memberEmployees}"
                     converter="employeeConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{lookupControl.employees}" 
                   var="emp" 
                   itemLabel="#{emp.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER}" 
                   itemValue="#{emp}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

I had never felt comfortable doing that in the past, without a documented guarantee that it works.  I just looked through the JSF specification and found this under its "Standard HTML RenderKit Tag Library" section:

> The following action must be taken to handle the value of the `converter` property. If `isLiteralText()` on the `converter` property returns `true`, get the value of the property and treat it as a `converterId` by passing it as the argument to the `createConverter()` method of the `Application` instance for this webapp, then pass the created `Converter` to the `setConverter()` method of the component for this tag.

So yes, passing a converter-id in the `converter=` attribute is completely supported.

Comment: Removing isn't needed. OP should just have used `converter="employeeConverter"`.